# How to find Spring-mapped method in the source by the URL?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-mvc

I'm debugging a project, an online banking website backend, that uses Spring. Often, all I have to latch on to in the bug report is which buttons to click to reproduce the bug. In the browser dev console, I then see the request URL and the response. I then have to somehow find the method mapped to that URL and start debugging.

What bothers me is that Eclipse's search features(that, or my ability to use them) leave a lot to be desired. I can't seem to find the method with one particular mapping, with something like `https://ourcompany.com/ourapp/delegate/rest/account/foo/info`
to work with, I string-search for "/info" or "/foo" or "foo/info", and get little results. All eclipse does is find some irrelevant file containing the string and open it, and then display(collapsed) a bunch of project folders below it, which I guess also contain files with the string somewhere in them.

Is there some more streamlined way to do this? Did I leave out something small but important from the search? How do I easily find which method in mapped to an URL such as the one in the example?

Comment: If you're using `spring-boot` with actuator support then you can hit your own `/mappings` endpoint.

Comment: Without understanding how the endpoints are set up, you're really searching in the dark with simple text searches like that. There are about a dozen ways I can think of that a deep endpoint like that might be configured, so you don't know what portion of the path to search for. Use Eclipse's search to find all the controller classes, then browse them to find which implements the endpoint you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to set a breakpoint inside

```
 org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter
```

See the method

```
@Override
public final ModelAndView handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
        throws Exception {

    return handleInternal(request, response, (HandlerMethod) handler);
}
```

here you have handler object which keeps class you need. Not sure it works in 100% cases.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using annotations, it should be easy to find the controller just searching the Java class files. I would start by searching for the account controller. In here, I believe you will find a method mapped to "{id}/info" which should be what you're looking for.

As a sidenote, IntelliJ may be something to look into if you're looking for a fuller feature set. I work with it daily for Java, Spring, Struts, and web files, and it does a great job indexing and finding results with ease.